# Issue in deploying spring mvc project on Jboss Fuse

Tags: spring-mvc, osgi, jbossfuse

I have created a sample web application (Spring MVC) project using Maven. I am trying to deploy it on Jboss fuse container however running into one error or other.

I have used spring mvc to create the webapp. The web.xml, dispatcher servlet, controller code and pom.xml have been attached below:
I created a new jboss fuse instance and installed following bundles to support spring mvc functionality

```
install -s mvn:org.aopalliance/com.springsource.org.aopalliance/1.0.0
features:install spring-dm
```

To deploy war file i use below command:

```
install war:mvn:com.proj.myproj.dsp/HelloWeb/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/war?Web-ContextPath=HelloWeb
```

The bundle however remains in Installed state. When i try to force restart it I get this error

```
org.eclipse.jetty.aggregate.jetty-all-server - 8.1.14.v20131031 | FAILED HelloWeb: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.core.GenericTypeResolver.resolveTypeArguments(Ljava/lang/Class;Ljava/lang/Class;)[Ljava/lang/Class;
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.core.GenericTypeResolver.resolveTypeArguments(Ljava/lang/Class;Ljava/lang/Class;)[Ljava/lang/Class;
    at org.springframework.core.convert.support.GenericConversionService.getRequiredTypeInfo(GenericConversionService.java:260)
```

Please point me to what mistake I am making here. Code of this project below:

Pom.xml (Snapshot)

```
<groupId>com.proj.myproj</groupId>
  <artifactId>HelloWeb</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>HelloWeb Maven Webapp</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

  <packaging>war</packaging>

  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
        <extensions>true</extensions>
        <configuration>
          <instructions>
            <Import-Package>
              *
            </Import-Package>
          </instructions>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.8.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.8.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.8.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.osgi</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-osgi-web</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.1</version>
    </dependency>

  </dependencies>
```

Web.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="2.4"
   xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" 
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee 
   http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">

   <display-name>Spring MVC Application</display-name>

   <servlet>
      <servlet-name>HelloWeb</servlet-name>
      <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
      <init-param>
            <param-name>contextClass</param-name>
            <param-value>org.springframework.osgi.web.context.support.OsgiBundleXmlWebApplicationContext</param-value>
      </init-param>
      <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
   </servlet>

   <servlet-mapping>
      <servlet-name>HelloWeb</servlet-name>
      <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
   </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

Dispatcher servlet

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

   <context:component-scan base-package="com.tutorialspoint" />

   <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
      <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
      <property na***strong text***me="suffix" value=".jsp" />
   </bean>

</beans>
```

Controller

```
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.ui.ModelMap;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/hello")
public class HelloController{

   @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
   public String printHello(ModelMap model) {
      System.out.println("Request comes to controller");
      model.addAttribute("message", "Hello Spring MVC Framework!");

      return "hello";
   }

}
```

If you need any other details please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

cause of `NoSuchMethodError` is almost due to conflicting library versions. In this case I'm guessing there are multiple versions of spring libraries. Use `osgi:list` to list the installed bundles.

hope this helps